# SQL partial update of columns based on case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Recently I have had to do a few variable updates to a table, and although I am aware of the MERGE statement (although need to catch up on all of that!), I also performed the following statement to optional update a table and wish to check if this is "a good idea" or has some hidden consequences that I not aware of.

So in my case, I pass a primary key to a table, however depending on if parameters passed are null or not, I update the column.. obviously if you had to ensure a forceful update (of a status etc.) then you would just update the column.. this is to save having multiple "IF / THEN" type structures..

```
create procedure sp_myprocedure
as
   @id                     bigint,
   @field1                 int = null,
   @field2                 varchar(255) = null,
   @field3                 char(1) = null
begin 

   update my_table
   set 
      field1 = case when @field1 is not null then @field1 else field1 end,
      field2 = case when @field2 is not null then @field2 else field2 end,
      field3 = case when @field3 is not null then @field3 else field3 end,
   where
      id = @id

end
```

Just after some thoughts of the above or is it best to pursue the MERGE statement for scenarios like the above?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine although it can be written in a cleaner way.

```
   update my_table
   set 
      field1 = coalesce (@field1,field1)
     ,field2 = coalesce (@field2,field2)
     ,field3 = coalesce (@field3,field3)
   where
      id = @id and coalesce(@field1,@field2,@field3) is not null
```

---

You can also move the `coalesce(@field1,@field2,@field3) is not null` to a wrapper block

```
if coalesce(@field1,@field2,@field3) is not null
begin

   update my_table
   set 
      field1 = coalesce (@field1,field1)
     ,field2 = coalesce (@field2,field2)
     ,field3 = coalesce (@field3,field3)
   where
      id = @id

end
```

---

**MERGE** statement is not relevant here.
With **MERGE** the decision is if to **INSERT**, **UPDATE** or **DELETE** a record base on the non-existent/existent of a record with the same merge keys in the source/target table.
In your case it is always **UPDATE**.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the alternative.  So the coalesce would appear more efficient?  or is the coalesce function more "standard"?
I suppose both read pretty well from an understanding perspective, but just wanted to know if one of the above ways is more standrd/performant if possible?

Comment: Option 2 is preffered since it in not even going execute the update statement if there is no need.

Comment: @onedaywhen, does MERGE come with the functionality of conditional update? Does Merge have any advantage of any kind (functionality / performance / syntax) over UPDATE in this use-case? No and no.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: no advantage, no disadvantage, just different. But "MERGE statement is not relevant here" is a misstatement.

Comment: "Not relevant here",  because the OP thought it might be a better solution while it has no value over what he already did.

Answer (score 2):

```
        create procedure sp_myprocedure

        @id                     bigint,
        @field1                 int = null,
        @field2                 varchar(255) = null,
        @field3                 char(1) = null
        as
        begin 
        IF coalesce(@field1,@field2,@field3) is not null
           update dbo.my_table
           set 
           field1 = coalesce (@field1,field1),
           field2 = coalesce (@field2,field2),
           field3 = coalesce (@field3,field3)
           where id = @id
        END
```

Answer (score 1):

Responding to the answer by @Dudu Markovitz:

> MERGE statement is not relevant here.

I disagree , I think `MERGE` is entirely relevant here.

The idea is to create a source table expression using the parameter values with which to update the target table:

```
MERGE my_table T
   USING ( VALUES ( @id, @field1, @field2, @field3 ) ) 
      AS S ( id, field1, field2, field3 )
      ON T.id = S.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET field1 = COALESCE( S.field1, T.field1 ),
          field2 = COALESCE( S.field2, T.field2 ),
          field3 = COALESCE( S.field3, T.field3 );
```

Of course, if there was a single table-valued parameter (as arguable there should be) then the relevance of `MERGE` is even more obvious.

Comment: So it can be done, with no advantage over a simple UPDATE statement.   You could have claimed for that matter that the same result can been achieved  using `CTAS`, `DROP TABLE` and `RENAME TABLE`.

Comment: Edit suggested.